# Display the whole content of object in array even if it is too long

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, datatables

I thought it was an issue with CSS so I have tried `overflow:auto`, `text-overflow:ellipsis` and `display:flex` in td

Here is my HTML

```
    <div class="box" style="overflow-x: auto; height: 90%">
              <div class="box-body">
                <table id="applicant_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                  <tbody>
                       <?php foreach($app_array as arr) { ?>
                    <tr>
                         "<td>" echo $arr->coverletter "</td>"
                          <?php
                          }
                          ?>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
```

How can I display the whole content of my array?

Comment: This depends on the JavaScript datatable library.

Comment: @Barmar I am using jQuery. What kind of datatable library can I have?

Comment: Read the documentation of the jQuery-Datatables library to see how you specify that the column widths should be flexible instead of fixed size.

Comment: @Barmar still don't get it fixed. I have used ```autoWidth:false``` , ```table.columns.adjust().draw();```. Is there any better one? Thank you

Comment: Try `autoWidth: true`

Comment: @Barmar I also tried but it didn't do anything

Comment: You need to post your datatable code, not PHP. I don't know DataTables well, maybe someone else will be able to help.

Comment: Show us your generated html. That will help

Comment: Keep in mind that when making changes on the client side you need to refresh the cache in most cases for changes to take effect (i.e. ctrl+F5).

Comment: @dap.tci I tried to show the generated html. Unfortunately, it's hard for me to do that with php and over 2000 length of string. But I can give you a part of my php shortened if you want.

Comment: @EternalHour for sure. I refresh every time.

Comment: @ewef, ok. So, it seems to be a CSS problem then. Try to reduce the size of your strings and show us the generated HTML and the CSS you are using. It is not a backend problem. We need to see your frontend

Comment: @dap.tci I added my code as much as I can. I really appreciate your consideration

Comment: @ewef, check my answer, please. Let me know if it was enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is when you are iterating over the array. You should put the foreach before `<tr>`, as following below:

```
<table id="applicant_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($app_array as arr) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $arr->coverletter ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much but it changes nothing. I have just learned that php holds all data in an array but dataTable doesn't display all of them. I think it is an issue with jQuery datatable

Comment: I didn't know you were using jQuery Datatable. I think you didn't mention it. In this case, you should show your JS code. Otherwise, it will be hard to help.